# Naive demosaic for bayer images

Tags: c++, image

I have this legacy code and I don't really think this is easy to read/maintain it. Can you suggest a way to make this more readable while still saving the performance?

```
template<typename T>
    void static ConvertBayerToRgbImageDemosaic(T* BayerChannel, T* RgbChannel, int Width, int Height, ColorSpace ColorSpace)
    {
        //Translates index offset in Bayer image to channel offset in RGB image
        int offsets[4];
        std::vector<int> colorOffsets[4];
        //calculate offsets according to color space
        switch (ColorSpace)
        {
        case ColorSpace::BGGR:
            offsets[0] = 2;
            offsets[1] = 1;
            offsets[2] = 1;
            offsets[3] = 0;
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(1);
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(Width);
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(Width + 1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(-Width - 1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(-Width);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(0);
            break;
        case ColorSpace::RGGB:
            offsets[0] = 0;
            offsets[1] = 1;
            offsets[2] = 1;
            offsets[3] = 2;
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(1);
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(Width);
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(Width + 1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(-Width - 1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(-Width);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(0);
            break;
        case ColorSpace::GBRG:
            offsets[0] = 1;
            offsets[1] = 2;
            offsets[2] = 0;
            offsets[3] = 1;
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(Width - 1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(Width);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(-Width);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(-Width + 1);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(0);
            break;
        case ColorSpace::GRBG:
            offsets[0] = 1;
            offsets[1] = 0;
            offsets[2] = 2;
            offsets[3] = 1;
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[0].push_back(1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(Width - 1);
            colorOffsets[1].push_back(Width);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(-Width);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(-Width + 1);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(0);
            colorOffsets[2].push_back(1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
            colorOffsets[3].push_back(0);
            break;
        default:
            throw "Unsupported colorSpace. Only bayer supported.";
        }

        #pragma omp parallel for    
        for (auto row = 0; row < Height; row++)
        {
            for (auto col = 0, bayerIndex = row * Width; col < Width; col++, bayerIndex++)
            {
                auto offset = (row % 2)*2 + (col % 2); //0...3
                std::for_each(colorOffsets[offset].begin(), colorOffsets[offset].end(), 
                    [&](int colorOffset)
                {
                    auto rgbIndex = (bayerIndex + colorOffset) * 3 + offsets[offset];
                    RgbChannel[rgbIndex] = BayerChannel[bayerIndex];
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Proposed changes:

To shorten that huge switch statement a little bit you could extract the `offsets` into a few constant arrays, since those are not dependent on the function inputs.

```
const int offsets_BGGR[4] = { 2, 1, 1, 0 };
const int offsets_RGGB[4] = { 0, 1, 1, 2 };
const int offsets_GBRG[4] = { 1, 2, 0, 1 };
const int offsets_GRBG[4] = { 1, 0, 2, 1 };
```

Then just grab a pointer to the appropriate array in the `switch` cases.

But going further, I would also extract the `switch` statement into a separate helper function. Something like a `GetColorSpaceConversionOffsets()`.

---

The `BayerChannel` parameter is only read from, so it should be marked `const`. This will be a valuable hint to callers of the function, since they can rest assured that the source data will remain unchanged upon function completion (unless there is a bug, of course).

---

Input parameter validation?

At the moment you are not doing any, which means that if a null pointer is passed as one of the parameters, the code would crash without much information about the error. Consider at the very least [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)ing to validate the inputs and help catching errors early.

---

A couple other minor points:

- Avoid throwing native types, such as raw strings and integers. The C++ Standard provides a set of throwable classes in the [`<stdexcept>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) standard header, that you can use instead. Most commonly you will throw a `runtime_error` for generic runtime problems, but you can also define a custom exception class to make error reporting more detailed.
- Use `camelCase` with the first letter lowercase for variables and function parameters, reserving `PascalCase` for types. For instance, in your function the `ColorSpace` type name confuses itself with the variable instance name:

  ```
  void static ConvertBayerToRgbImageDemosaic(T* BayerChannel, T* RgbChannel, 
               int Width, int Height, ColorSpace ColorSpace) { ...
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

---

#### Updated code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

enum class ColorSpace
{
    BGGR, RGGB, GBRG, GRBG
};

// Local data and helpers "hidden" inside an anonymous namespace.
namespace
{

const int offsets_BGGR[4] = { 2, 1, 1, 0 };
const int offsets_RGGB[4] = { 0, 1, 1, 2 };
const int offsets_GBRG[4] = { 1, 2, 0, 1 };
const int offsets_GRBG[4] = { 1, 0, 2, 1 };

void GetColorSpaceConversionOffsets(ColorSpace colorSpace, int width, std::vector<int> colorOffsets[4], const int *& offsets)
{
    // Calculate offsets according to color space
    switch (colorSpace)
    {
    case ColorSpace::BGGR:
        offsets = offsets_BGGR;
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(1);
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(width);
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(width + 1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(-width - 1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(-width);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(0);
        break;
    case ColorSpace::RGGB:
        offsets = offsets_RGGB;
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(1);
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(width);
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(width + 1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(-width - 1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(-width);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(0);
        break;
    case ColorSpace::GBRG:
        offsets = offsets_GBRG;
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(width - 1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(width);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(-width);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(-width + 1);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(0);
        break;
    case ColorSpace::GRBG:
        offsets = offsets_GRBG;
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[0].push_back(1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(width - 1);
        colorOffsets[1].push_back(width);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(-width);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(-width + 1);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(0);
        colorOffsets[2].push_back(1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
        colorOffsets[3].push_back(0);
        break;
    default:
        throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported ColorSpace. Only bayer supported.");
    }
}

} // namespace {}

template<typename T>
void ConvertBayerToRgbImageDemosaic(const T* bayerChannel, T* rgbChannel, int width, int height, ColorSpace colorSpace)
{
    // Translates index offset in Bayer image to channel offset in RGB image
    std::vector<int> colorOffsets[4];
    const int * offsets = nullptr;
    GetColorSpaceConversionOffsets(colorSpace, width, colorOffsets, offsets);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (auto row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (auto col = 0, bayerIndex = row * width; col < width; col++, bayerIndex++)
        {
            auto offset = (row % 2) * 2 + (col % 2); // 0...3

            std::for_each(colorOffsets[offset].begin(), colorOffsets[offset].end(),
                [&](int colorOffset)
                {
                    auto rgbIndex = (bayerIndex + colorOffset) * 3 + offsets[offset];
                    rgbChannel[rgbIndex] = bayerChannel[bayerIndex];
                });
        }
    }
}
```